# I am very beginner to java could any one explain it please why I am getting "InputmismatchExcetion" here?

Tags: java

Here i am trying to Enter and Print some details of employe and everything looks fine but i am getting an Exception why?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;  

    class EmpDet

        {  //here details
              int age;    
              String name;    
              int ssn;  
          public EmpDet(int age,String name,int ssn)    
        {  
           //assign to constructor

            this.age = age;    
            this. name = name;  
            this.ssn = ssn;  
            System.out.println(age+" "+name+" "+ssn); //printing details

        }  

            public static void main(String args[])  
            {  
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
                int age = sc.nextInt();  

                String name = sc.nextLine(); //InputMismatchException in this line
                int ssn = sc.nextInt();  
                EmpDet det = new EmpDet(age,name,ssn);  
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you get the exception, was there any text for `sc.nextLine()` to pick up?

Comment: are you putting dashes - in your ssn?

Comment: @hellyale I believe the exception is occurring on the line with `sc.nextLine`, not `sc.nextInt`.

Comment: have you tried debugging?

Comment: [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--) **cannot** throw `InputMismatchException`. You're getting the error in the `ssn = sc.nextInt()` call, because it sees the "name", given that `nextLine()` didn't see the name (see [duplicate link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045/5221149)).

Comment: When mixing nextXxx() calls with nextLine() calls, you have to flush (discard) the end of the previous line by calling nextLine() first.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to grab line by line instead. Once you have the line, then you can try to parse the input into an Integer.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
    int age = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());  

    String name = sc.nextLine();
    int ssn = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());  
    EmpDet det = new EmpDet(age,name,ssn);
```

It would be also wise to put a try catch around the parsing in case the input from the user doesn't qualify as being an Integer.

Note, nextInt() only grabs the number and not the new line (enter)